# Bad stdio forwarding specification '%h:%p''

Tags: bash, macos, shell

[OS - macOS, Shell - Bash]

I have a small bash script that generates a ssh command based on input parameters. The command generated is:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh <bastion_name> -W %h:%p' -A -D <port> <username>@<destination_host_name>
```

The script stores this command in a variable say cmd, where

```
cmd="ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh $1 -W %h:%p' -A -D $3 $4@$2"
```

where $1 = bastion_name, $2 = destination_host_name, $3 = port and $4 = username.

and then it tries to execute the command like,

```
echo "Executing --> $cmd"
$cmd
```

but it terminates with following error,

```
Bad stdio forwarding specification '%h:%p''
```

But since I am echoing the cmd, I copy paste directly in terminal and it runs without any error.

Please note the bastion_name is resolved via ssh config which has the username and other attributes defined for that bastion host.

What's the problem here because obviously the command is correct ?

Comment: Don't put commands in variables, they're for data, not executable code. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) Either execute the command directly, or use a function, or (if necessary) use an array.

Comment: There could be scenarios where your intention might be to save the executable as data. Here's an example of such a scenario: Create a script that would loop through environmental variables that match a specific pattern and execute the command passed via an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try not to use eval, cause it's evil.

Always quote your variables (unless you have a reason not to). Never `$cmd` always `"$cmd"`.

Use bash arrays:

```
cmd=(ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh '"$1"' -W %h:%p' -A -D "$3" "$4@$2")

echo "Executing -->" "${cmd[@]}"
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Learn more about quoting [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).

@edit: Took the `$1` part out of single quotes, cause OPs intent is to expand it. Fixed executing --> line.

Comment: This does not work on macOS. 

`cmd=(ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh $1 -W %h:%p' -A -D "$3" "$4@$2")`

`echo "$cmd"`
Output --> `ssh`

Comment: `cmd=("-o ProxyCommand='ssh $bastion -W %h:%p' -A -D $port $user@$host")
eval "ssh ${cmd[@]}"`

This worked. I think you meant to have the `ssh` out of the array. Also, it does not work without `eval`.

Comment: I mean it as I wrote it..In the first comment `echo "$cmd"` is equal to `echo "${cmd[0]}"` - it will print only the first element of an array. Use `echo "${cmd[@]}"` to print them all. In the second comment `eval "ssh ${cmd[@]}"` is evil - `cmd=("-o ... ; rm -rf / "); eval "ssh ${cmd[@]}";` will format your drive. You can `sshargs=$(-o ProxyCommand=' ' ...); ssh "${sshargs[@]}";`. It works on my pc. I will edit the post, cause probably your want the `$1` to exapnd too. You can read about quoting [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: My bad, the echo was wrong, I missed to print all array elements but the command didn't run without the `eval`. Anyway I have a solution now posted as answer. Also, agreed on `eval` is evil but for my use case it's safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
cmd=("-o ProxyCommand='ssh $bastion -W %h:%p' -A -D $port $user@$host")
echo "Executing --> $cmd"
eval "ssh ${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: Don't use `eval` -- the only reason it works here is that you have the quoting wrong  when you define the array. Essentially, you have two mistakes here (quoting and `eval`) that mostly cancel each other out. But only mostly. It's better to just get the quoting right in the first place. See @KamilCuk's latest edit.